# What does "a woman of mean understanding" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, literary-english

In the end of the first chapter of Jane Austin's *Pride and Prejudice*, Mrs. Bennet is described as a "woman of mean understanding". On the Web, I found two meanings:

1. of little knowledge
2. bad temper

Can someone clarify the meaning of "mean understanding" in my context?

Comment: I have always taken it to mean 'stupid' in this particular case, but the difference between that and your 1) is small (though small differences can be vital in Austen). Where did you find 2)? It might be right if the phrase were *of mean character*, but not as written.

Comment: Yeah, I'd understand "mean" as equivalent to "not generous" in this case.

Comment: You can describe a person as _mean_, meaning "not generous". But in this case I have no doubt that it meant _little understanding_. IIRC it is paired with _uncertain temper_ in the original.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means of “of common understanding”: she didn’t understand much.  The OED gives:

> **II** Inferior in rank or quality.
>
> **2a.** Of persons, their rank or station: Undistinguished in position; of low degree; often opposed to noble or gentle.   (Cf. **common** *adj.* <sup>12</sup>).) *Obs*.

But the citations date up through the 19<sup>th</sup> century, so it was not yet “obsolete” in the time of Jane Austen.

Frankly, I’m not sure I would mark it obsolete so much as literary.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be a transferred epithet. The woman was mean, rather than her understanding.